org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException
While executing a thirdParty API call using jakarta ClientBuilder, I am getting the following exception
(vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) A blocking operation occurred on the IO thread. This likely means you need to use the @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking annotation on the Resource method, class or jakarta.
Here is the following snipet code which produces a error:

 import static jakarta.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;

    public WenTokenInfoResolver() {
        client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature.class).build();
    }


    public UserInfo fetchUserInfo(final String userToken) throws WenTokenInfoResolverFailureException {
        return UserInfo.fromResponse(client.target(ConfigHelper.wenBaseUrl).path(ConfigHelper.wenInfoOAuth).request().header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + userToken).get(JSONObject.class));
    }

I tried configuring @Blocking @nonBlocking on the controller level and still the same error.

Can you show more code of where the client is used?

@geoand I have updated the code snipet
